# $\sigma$-algebra generated by two random variables

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

It is actually exercise 8.8 in Oksendal SDE book. Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion and $Z_t$ be a 1-dimensional Ito process of the form
$$dZ_t = u(t,\omega) dt + dB_t.$$
Let $\mathcal{Z}_t$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{Z_s : s \leq t\}$. Let
$$ dN_t = \Big(u(t,\omega) - E[u(t,\omega)|\mathcal{Z}_t]\Big)dt + dB_t.$$
I want to prove that $N_t$ is a Brownian motion.

Let $\mathcal{N}_t$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{N_s : s \leq t\}$. I think that it is enough to prove that $E\Big[u(t,\omega) - E[u(t,\omega)|\mathcal{Z}_t] \hspace{2pt} \Big| \hspace{2pt} \mathcal{N}_t\Big] = 0$.
It is sufficient to prove that $\mathcal{N}_t \subset \mathcal{Z}_t$, since
$$ E\Big[u(t,\omega) - E[u(t,\omega)|\mathcal{Z}_t] \hspace{2pt} \Big| \hspace{2pt} \mathcal{N}_t\Big] 
= E\Big[u(t,\omega) \hspace{2pt} \Big| \hspace{2pt} \mathcal{N}_t\Big] 
- E\Big[E[u(t,\omega)|\mathcal{Z}_t] \hspace{2pt} \Big| \hspace{2pt} \mathcal{N}_t\Big]=0.$$
We have $dN_t = dZ_t - E[u(t,\omega)|\mathcal{Z}_t]dt$ and it is equivalent to
$$ N_t = N_0+ Z_t -Z_0 + g(t), $$
for some $g(t)$. But I do not know to prove the subset relation due to the presence of $N_0$ and $Z_0$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but $N_0$ *must* be a constant random variable, like $N_0 = x$ for some $x$ or something. That's because every theorem there assumes that we are beginning from a certain point. Under that, I think the proof is kind of obvious. You made the right guess : indeed, the representation $dN_t = dZ_t - E[u(t,\omega) | \mathcal Z_t] dt$ is the expression of $N_t$ as a stochastic integral in $Z_t$ plus a measurable function in $Z_t$, since $E[u(t,\omega) | \mathcal Z_t]$ is obviously $\mathcal Z_t$ measurable, and the $t$-integral retains adaptedness.